# Order by query is taking too much time

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 80k plus customers and having 4 groups. Now I want to find 2 groups users with a query in mysql. My query is like below:

```
select c.customers_firstname as recipient_firstname, 
       c.customers_lastname as  recipient_lastname,
       c.customers_id as recipient_id, 
       c.customers_email_address as recipient_email_address 
from customers c
where customers_group_id = '1' OR customers_group_id = '3'
```

When I run this query in phpmyadmin I got the result : **Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 59,815 total, Query took 0.0034 sec)**

But when I added order by `ORDER BY recipient_firstname ASC` in this query the result time is : **Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 59,815 total, Query took 0.2607 sec)**

the order by query is taking too much time for the result.

I want to reduce the time of order by query.

Please help if there is another way to get the same result in less time.

Comment: Create an index on `recipient_firstname` field. Also, try: `where customers_group_id  IN (1, 3)`

Comment: Well, as always when having trouble with performance of specific queries against mysql: try the great 'explain' feature in mysql! It tells you where the problem is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an index on the `recipient_firstname` field (so really customers.customers_firstname). An index allows for an ordered, linear time iteration over the result set.

If you don't have an index, the result set must be aggregated and then sorted. This sorting is going to be `n log n`. That's obviously pretty slow for large sets, and if it can't fit into memory (and 60k records might not depending on configuration), it's going to do a very slow file based sort.

**tl;dr** You need an index. An index on `recipient_firstname` will make the query extremely close in performance to the non `ORDER BY` version.

---

By the way, if customers_group_id is an integral field, use integer literals, not strings. It likely won't make a difference, but it's misleading, and there are actually a few situations where it matters.

---

Depending on the situation, it's probably also worth putting an index on the group id. For small sets, the results can just be filtered as the set is built, but for large result sets, that will end up requiring a rather disk heavy full table scan.

Comment: Don't you think index should include group_id as well? since that is part of WHERE and ignoring that might make this query slow later with more data even if not now

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky As fast as his unordered query is running, I'm assuming he already has an index on group_id.

Comment: I think it could be because its an integer value and 80k records are nothing for an integer comparison. Might be worth a mention to complement your answer

Answer (score 3):

You have to index on the `customers_firstname` field: this will speed up the `ORDER BY`, *but will also slow down the `WHERE`* (which is probably indexed now).

So the index must be `customers_group_id, customers_firstname` in this order.

```
CREATE INDEX my_query_ndx 
    ON customers ( customers_group_id, customers_firstname );
```

In theory you might enlarge the index to be a *covering index* and contain, after the two key fields, all other fields you require in the `SELECT`. Maintaining this kind of index is expensive, though; you'll have to balance advantages and drawbacks. If the table is very "wide", it might be advantageous to index on group id, firstname, lastname, id and email.

## Small (or not so small) query improvements

```
where customers_group_id = '1' OR customers_group_id = '3'
```

This can be rewritten for clarity (it changes nothing) as

```
WHERE customers_group_id IN ('1','3')
```

But now, either `customer_group_id` is an integer field, or it isn't. If it is, then it's better to treat is as such:

```
WHERE customers_group_id IN (1, 3)
```

In some cases, you can plan ahead your IDs so that for example group 3 is actually group 2, i.e., the groups you might be interested in are contiguous. That way, you can rewrite the query as `variable < value` or `variable > value` or `variable BETWEEN`, which is twice as fast as an `OR`. With large `OR` sets you can get 4x speedups easily.

If it is not an integer field, then by all means strive to make it one. Integer performance (and index size) will benefit greatly (note, however, that with strings, '3' is greater than '12', just as 'C' is greater than 'AB'; so, type conversion is not necessarily without side effects).

Answer (score 1):

Try to create index `(customers_group_id, customers_firstname)` - this should work.

Comment: Why not go ahead and edit it when we know this was a typo only and doesn't change answer's design

Answer (score 0):

You need to [create index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) on column on which order by clause is applied.

```
CREATE INDEX index_name ON customers (customers_firstname);
```